# Filling up array with positive integers

Tags: c++

I tried to fill up an array with 'n' numbers, but i got stuck. So here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n]={};

    for (int i = 0;i <= n; i++) {
        for(int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
            cout << arr[i] = k;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

}

So if u will input 3, it will output 1,2,3;
In my code I tried to make a loop, that does the filling up array starting from 0 to n,and fill up with numbers from 1 to n.
Help me pls!

Comment: `int arr[n]` is not valid C++ (VLA extension), use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You need only one loop.

Comment: And avoid complex expressions such as `cout << arr[i] = k`.

Comment: [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) might help.

Comment: [`std::vector<int> arr(n);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) then  [`std::iota(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 1);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) - done.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the standard algorithms you can use [`std::iota(first, last, value)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) which fills the range `[first, last)` with sequentially increasing values, starting with the given `value` then incrementing by one each time. Then use [`std::for_each(first, last, function)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) to print the vector out. For the function, you can use a lambda function

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::vector<int> arr(n);
  std::iota(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 1);

  std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](int elem) -> void {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl
  });

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    cin>>n;
    int* arr =  new int[n];

    for (int i = 0;i < n; i++) //only `<` not `<=`
    {
        cout << arr[i] = i+1;
    }

    delete[] arr ;
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to complete your code

- You don't need two for loops one is enough.

**method**(array start from 0 to n)

```
int k = 1;
for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) { //i = 0 and i < n
       arr[i] = k;
       cout << arr[i];
       k++;
}
```

Hope this will fulfill your question

Comment: I have corrected it. when I run that part it didn't give me any error and output is also correct